# empty list from columns conditional

Tags: python, dataframe, null

I get the columns from a data frame, what I'm trying to do is, if columns is not empty do this... if is empty then do that... but I'm receiving the error: **ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()** by using the following code:

```
    sw_col = df_sw.columns
    if sw_col.notnull():
        miss = (sw_col) - (df.columns)
        print(miss)
    else:
        df_sw = pd.concat([df, df_sw], ignore_index=True)
```

I would appreciate your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the error you got, that's because `sw_col.notnull()` returns an array of boolean values and python cannot decide which element it should consider to execute if or else.

==========================================

(1) When you say columns is empty, do you mean dataframe is empty? Because, columns return the NAMES of columns. if that is the case, then you can use `df.empty` to check that.

(2) If that's not  the case and you are trying to see if the columns have names or not, I think your approach doesn't help since df.columns return the RangeIndex type object when there are no names for columns. So, you can then use `isinstance(sw_col, pd.RangeIndex)` to see if there are names for the columns of dataframe or not. If it returns True, it means the columns have no pre-defined names.

(3) If you are trying to search for empty columns in a dataframe (columns with no elements), then you can apply `df.notnull()` and it will return True for each element if it exist in the dataframe. So, then to find the columns that are COMPLETELY EMPTY without even a single element, you can just use a.any() on each column.